# Hide everything comes outside form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML structure is like this

```
 <body>
    <form></form>
    <div></div>
    <center></center>
</body>
```

I want to hide everything outside  <`form></form>` using  css or javascript. means output will be something like this

```
<body>
    <form></form>
    <div style="display: none"></div>
    <center style="display: none"></center>
</body>
```

I will prefer CSS as it can take over the case before dom loads.

Comment: Since you have accepted an answer that makes any element inside a form invisible, it is unclear what the question is about. Do you really have a `form` with no child elements? It’s difficult to imagine any use for it.

Comment: You should also specify exactly what the HTML structure is, not just “like this”. In particular, is the `form` element always a child of `body`, is it always the first element there, and is it always the only `form` element on the page? Oh, and in which sense should all the rest be hidden? Setting `display: none` is different from `visibility: hidden` (and both are different from other methods that could be called hiding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}

body form {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLQfk/)

### Edit

To make inside form elements visible, just add:

```
body form * {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: This makes any element inside the `form` invisible.

Comment: Agreeing with Jukka... This will not work... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLQfk/1/)

Comment: @Fabricio See the edit. You are about 50 minutes late.

Comment: @Beterraba No matter the lateness (due to open page during lunch) Adil's solution is far superior and deserves to be the selected solution.

Comment: @Fabricio Adil solutions just works if the form is the first child of body. So, not so "superior". :)

Comment: @Beterraba Are you really sure about what you are saying? :-) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricis/Hv6x2/4/)

Comment: @Fabricio [that](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv6x2/5/) is what I mean. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I understand your point but then you are answering a different question. ;-) .oO(Mental note: next time close browser before going for lunch)

Comment: @Fabricio But my original answer satisfies OP question (there are a empty form there)! lol

Comment: LOL Right... You win... :-D

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly for me :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `parent-child` selector with `:not`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv6x2/3/)**

```
body > *:not(form)
{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: This works (with the usual CSS caveats), if the `form` element is a child of `body` (as it is in the description in the question, but often not in real life).

Comment: I followed what OP wants, that could be handled with another css

Answer (score 2):

if you want to hide other tags

```
 * {display: none;}
```

Then show tags you want to be shown

```
form {display: block;}
```

you can also try :not(tag_name) if you want css not t be assigned to this specific tag_name or you can use class name for :not()

to show inside form

```
form, form * {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
 $(":not(form)").hide()
```

Comment: This also hides any element inside a `form` element. Although the question has `<form></form>`, there are surely inner elements; without them, a `form` element would be pointless.

Answer (score 2):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7sh5/)

```
body > * {
    display: none;
}
form.show {
    display: block !important;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    width:200px;
    height:300px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to make this complete. You can also hide everthing that follows after `<form>`.

```
form ~ *
{
    display: none;
}
```

But the answer of @Beterraba is definitely correct for your question.